# invalid input syntax for type postgres function

Tags: sql, function, postgresql

I have this Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION year_2014.insertsub
(
  accountid      integer,
  analyseid      integer,
  analysedate    date,
  requestnumber  integer
)
RETURNS integer AS
$$
DECLARE r integer;
begin
FOR r IN SELECT public."SubAnalyze".id FROM  public."SubAnalyze" where public."SubAnalyze".analyze_id = analyseid
loop
   INSERT INTO year_2014."Results"(account_id, analyze_id, "date", subanalyze_id, requestnumber)
VALUES
    (accountid, analyseid, 'analysedate', r, requestnumber);
END LOOP;
RETURN 1; 
end
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
VOLATILE
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER
COST 100;

ALTER FUNCTION year_2014.insertsub(accountid integer, analyseid integer, analysedate date, requestnumber integer)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

when I run the function error message

SQL Error: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: "analysedate"
LINE 3:     (accountid, analyseid, 'analysedate', r, requestnumber)
                                   ^
QUERY:  INSERT INTO year_2014."Results"(account_id, analyze_id, "date", subanalyze_id, requestnumber)
VALUES
    (accountid, analyseid, 'analysedate', r, requestnumber)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function year_2014.insertsub(integer,integer,date,integer) line 6 at SQL statement

Answer (score 0):

Don't quote 'analysedate', in this way you send the text analysedate to your insert command instead of a date, the correct syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO year_2014."Results"(account_id, analyze_id, "date", subanalyze_id, requestnumber)
VALUES
(accountid, analyseid, analysedate, r, requestnumber);
```

Comment: when I remove quote and run Function:    SQL Error: ERROR:  function year_2014.insertsub(integer, integer, integer, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM year_2014.insertsub(7, 14, 12/12/2014, 9) LIMI...
                      ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.